# How to stdin with barcode/qrcode scanner in python3 / input data / raspberry pi4 / python

Tags: python, python-3.x, qr-code, raspberry-pi4

I am Korean, so the translation may be difficult. There is a qr scanner of usb input.
I am trying to process data when data is scanned by qr scanner using Python in the Raspberry Pi 4 environment.

When I scanned the qr code with the qr code scanner, I confirmed that the data was output. But I don't know how to do it with python input.

What should I do?
Thank you very much for writing an example of Python code.

Comment: Are you trying to read the output of the USB QR scanner from a Python script?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just put

```
my_qr_code = input("Scan QR code:")
```

Basic example

```
print(input("Scan QR code:"))
```

Any barcode scanner that is recognized by the machine as a HID device will be indistinguishable to the Python interpreter from a person typing the digits comprising the barcode and pressing Enter.

Comment: I tried it that way, but how do I recognize when the qr code is scanned once?
In the end, you have to press Enter, so can you automatically scan and input it once?

Comment: I want to complete the basic function of outputting data when the qr code is scanned while waiting for the qr code scan.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve it with Python code? I keep trying, but it's hard.